# How to create a list with data tables as items that can be sorted

Tags: java, android

**What I want to create**
I want to create a list where each item in that list is an data table like below: [image: Example data table] The user needs te be able to sort items in the data table and needs to  be able to sort the data tables itself.

Each table is going to represent a client and each item in that table is an order. The user will then collect the orders, if he collected an order the order wil dissapear but the user is also able to bring them back.

**What I tried**
I tried to put a Recyclerview inside a Recyclerview but this caused unitended side effects and bugs, also I read online that it is basically a bad practice. My initial intention was to use a recylcerview with a sortedlist.

I did some searching online and a lot of people recommended using categories between items so that you only need one list. But because I have data tables (CardViews) that can be independent sorted this isn't an option.

If anyone want to give me a nudge in the right direction, I would be really thankful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do you can use recycler view and in custom row check box with 8 text views and when position is 0 inflate categories like fat, calcium etc and after that position populate data and if you want next button which shows next items in list use fragments or pagination that should do the trick and you can achieve this using single recycler view. You can also use header to show categories.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer, but the data table is inside a CardView like the example. So I can't use your method right?

Comment: so you want your recycler view  row that is card view according to you   to hold a listView or recycler view itself ?

Comment: Basically yes, but I tried that and it caused bugs even official Android docs say its not a good idea to put a recyclerview inside a recyclerview. But it needs to look the same as the example img.

Comment: then use Viewpager or fragments to load next data....each view pager or say fragment load only certain amount of data say 10-20 items in each fragment

Comment: Oké, but the amount of data tables can be 1 to 136. I don't think that viewpager is designed for that many fragments.

Comment: use pagination you dont have to create 136 fragments